# How To - Photoshop Script - Merge Two Layers

Tags: javascript, merge, photoshop, layer, extendscript

My Photoshop Canvas is 900X600.

The function below takes **Layer X** and makes **Layer X copy**.

It takes **Layer X copy** and while maintaining the ratio adjusts the height to 600px. `var newdLayer`

It takes **Layer X** and while maintaining the ratio adjusts the width to 900px and applies the Gaussian Blur. `var blur`.

I want to then merge **Layer X copy** and **Layer X**.

Apparently there is a `merge()` function, but for that you have to crate a `layerset`. Not really a pro at javascript.

How to merge the two layers?

```js
(function (){

var docRef = activeDocument
var newdLayer = docRef.activeLayer.duplicate();

newdLayer;

    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  
    var bounds = newdLayer.bounds;  
    var height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;
    var newSize = (100 / height) * 600;  
    newdLayer.resize(newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;  

var blur = docRef.activeLayer;

    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;  
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;  
    var bounds = blur.bounds;  
    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
    var newSize = (100 / width) * 900;  
    blur.resize(newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;  
    blur.applyGaussianBlur(5)

blur;


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your function by eliminating some redundant steps and added a snippet at the end that facilitates creating a new `layerSet`, moving the `newdLayer` and `blur` layers to the set, and merging that set:

```
(function (){

var docRef = activeDocument
var blur = docRef.activeLayer;
var newdLayer = blur.duplicate();

    var startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    // since we resize based on the initial size of the source layer, 
    // we don't need to get the bounds twice
    var bounds = blur.bounds;
    var height = bounds[3].value - bounds[1].value;
    var width = bounds[2].value - bounds[0].value;
    // declare 2 different vars for your sizes (there are better ways to do this, but
    // since you say you aren't a JavaScript pro, I figured I'd keep it simple)
    var newSize600 = (100 / height) * 600;
    var newSize900 = (100 / width) * 900;
    // resize your layers
    newdLayer.resize(newSize600, newSize600, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    blur.resize(newSize900, newSize900, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
    // apply blur
    blur.applyGaussianBlur(5);

    // below creates the group, moves the layers to it and merges them. Feel free to just include this part
    // at the end of your function if you don't want to use the modified code above. 

    // create a new layer set
    var groupOne = docRef.layerSets.add();

    // move the blur layer inside the layer set and name the layer for posterity
    blur.move(groupOne, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
    blur.name = "blur";

    // move the newdLayer inside and rename
    newdLayer.move(groupOne, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
    newdLayer.name = "newdLayer";

    // merge the layer set and name the new layer
    var mergedGroup = groupOne.merge();
    mergedGroup.name = "newdLayer + blur";

    app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;

})();
```

As a side note, a `merge()` method is available to `artLayers` as well, but depending on the number of layers your doc has and the order of the layers, it could require additional steps to merge the 2 layers with the `artLayers` method.  This is because the `artLayers` `merge()` method simply merges whichever layer is active with the one below it.  When layers are duplicated, I believe they are placed at index 0 in the `artLayers` collection, which would be the top most layer in the Layers palette.  If your source layer wasn't already at index 0, then you'd need to sort layers prior to `merge()`;

Comment: Works Great! Thanks!